# How do we find what packages exist in our tcl environment and where they are stored and how to include new packages?

Tags: tcl

My objective was to carry out log base 2 in my tcl script but it has raised some questions about how tcl works. I need to do these things:

1. Find list of available packages in my tcl environment
2. Find list of procedures available in package
3. Find "information" or "description" of procedure like we do using -h or --help switch in Shell
4. How to add new package into our tcl environment? Are there packages to be download for tcl as they are for Python (where we use pip)?

Now I have tried to carry out some command execution myself and the trace is below:

```
% info log
error: unknown or ambiguous subcommand "log": must be args, body, class, cmdcount, commands, complete, coroutine, default, errorstack, exists, frame, functions, globals, hostname, level, library, loaded, locals, nameofexecutable, object, patchlevel, procs, script, sharedlibextension, tclversion, or vars
    while executing
"info log"
% log(2.71)
error: invalid command name "log(2.71)"
    while executing
"log(2.71)"
% expr log(2.71)
0.9969486348916096
% info ::tcl::mathfunc
error: unknown or ambiguous subcommand "::tcl::mathfunc": must be args, body, class, cmdcount, commands, complete, coroutine, default, errorstack, exists, frame, functions, globals, hostname, level, library, loaded, locals, nameofexecutable, object, patchlevel, procs, script, sharedlibextension, tclversion, or vars
    while executing
"info ::tcl::mathfunc"
% info ::tcl::mathfunc::log
error: unknown or ambiguous subcommand "::tcl::mathfunc::log": must be args, body, class, cmdcount, commands, complete, coroutine, default, errorstack, exists, frame, functions, globals, hostname, level, library, loaded, locals, nameofexecutable, object, patchlevel, procs, script, sharedlibextension, tclversion, or vars
    while executing
"info ::tcl::mathfunc::log"
% expr ::tcl::mathfunc::log(2.71)
error: missing operand at _@_
in expression "_@_::tcl::mathfunc::log(2..."
    (parsing expression "::tcl::mathfunc::log(2...")
    invoked from within
"expr ::tcl::mathfunc::log(2.71)"
% info 
error: wrong # args: should be "info subcommand ?arg ...?"
    while executing
"info "
% info library
C:/intelFPGA/18.1/quartus/bin64/tcl8.6
% package names
systemconsole zlib TclOO tcl::tommath Tcl
% ::tcl::mathfunc::rand
0.6648586465347831
% info ::tcl::mathfunc::rand
error: unknown or ambiguous subcommand "::tcl::mathfunc::rand": must be args, body, class, cmdcount, commands, complete, coroutine, default, errorstack, exists, frame, functions, globals, hostname, level, library, loaded, locals, nameofexecutable, object, patchlevel, procs, script, sharedlibextension, tclversion, or vars
    while executing
"info ::tcl::mathfunc::rand"
```

The things confusing me about this trace are:

1. Carrying out "package names" returns "systemconsole zlib TclOO tcl::tommath Tcl" and this does not include ::tcl::mathfunc. Why is that? This list is way to small!
2. Why does log(2.71) return "invalid command name" error but expr log(2.71) works?
3. Why does expr ::tcl::mathfunc::log(2.71) fail but ::tcl::mathfunc::rand works? Aren't both part of the mathfunc package?

Comment: Technically, `log(2.71)` is a valid function name. It's just _very_ unusual to put parentheses in a name like that, as it is confusing when associative arrays are also in use.

Comment: Also, try running `info commands tcl::mathfunc::*` to get a list of all function-implementation commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finding Packages

1. Tcl waits to build the package list until you ask for a package whose name it does not currently know. `catch {package require thereisnosuchpackage}` should *mostly* populate the list.

   However, there are some packages that are stored as Tcl modules and that never get entered into the list. They use a more efficient loading mechanism, but are somewhat restricted in format. `tcl::tm::path list` will give a list of directories where they can be found, and the package name and version are built from that into a file.

   I don't like that there isn't a way to get a list of those modules neatly, even if just for maintenance and discovery purposes.

### Functions in Expressions

2. The `expr` command *rewrites* the call to the `log(1.23)` function from:

   ```
   expr { log(1.23) }
   ```

   into a call to:

   ```
   expr { [tcl::mathfunc::log [expr { 1.23 }]] }
   ```

   which ends up equivalent to:

   ```
   expr { [tcl::mathfunc::log 1.23] }
   ```

   which in turn ends up virtually equivalent to:

   ```
   tcl::mathfunc::log 1.23
   ```

   (The “virtually” is a *really* here because the log function returns a floating point number. There are some minor technical differences with custom functions.)
3. Note that the parentheses are gone in the above call; ***they're just syntax*** for expressions. Technically, expressions are their own little language embedded within Tcl (and that in turn embeds Tcl).

   The rewrite for `rand` just ends up removing the parentheses as it takes no arguments.

Comment: I can see that tcl is different from C in so many ways

Comment: I'm intrigued. Can you provide an example of a module that won't show up in the `package names` output?